# Generate a triangular pattern using two different symbols

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to generate a triangular thing like below:

```
a       (1px)
bb      (2px)
aaa     (3px)
bbbb    (4px)
```

However, I found that it won’t be triangular if two symbols have different sizes. For example, the result will be:

```
口
xx
口口口
xxxx
```

Here is my code:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--    

    window.alert("Hello! This website draws a triangular pattern.");
    var height; //the height of the triangular pattern
    var first; //the first symbol that forms the triangle 
    var second; //the second symbol that forms the triangle
    var display;


    height = window.prompt("What is the height of the triangular pattern?")
    first = window.prompt("Please enter a symbol to generate the triangular pattern:")
    second = window.prompt("Please enter another symbol to generate the triangular pattern:")


    h = parseInt(height);

    var i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= h; i++) {

      display = "<p style = \"font-size: " + i + "ex\">";

      for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        if (i % 2 > 0)
          display += first;

        if (i % 2 <= 0)
          display += second;
      }

      display += "</p>";
      document.write(display);
    }
    //-->
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is an exercise a found online but I forgot the source. I am required to only use a single HTML file to finish the task. I cannot use external CSS.

Simply saying, if first line total used *a* px, then the second line needs to use *2a* px, ignoring the sizes of symbols.

**And I want to know how can I make this. Like the below image.**

[image]

I think it is okay for me to generate the shape reluctantly if the sizes of symbols are nearly same. Hope the code above need not to change if there is no big problem as I want to keep some of my efforts seen.

Comment: My code cannot make a triangle when two symbols have different sizes.

Comment: I want to know what things should be added as simple as it can to solve the problem.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this. You could create a [`CanvasRenderingContext2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D), then use the [`measureText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) method or call [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for two lines containing only one of each character in order to figure out how big the characters are, but this is more advanced use of the DOM API.

Answer (score 1):

Set the line-height to 1px. Change your first statement inside the for loop to below code

```
display = "<p style = \"font-size: " + i + "ex; line-height: " + i +"px\">";
```

You will get something like

[image]